# Ruby 2's Makefile vs Cygwin

Tags: makefile, cygwin, ruby-2.0

My outer problem is I'd like to get Ruby (WITH Nokogiri!) working on Win7. I'm tired of running a virtual Linux just to play with my toys.

My inner problem is this:

```
make[1]: *** No rule to make target ` '.  Stop.
```

It says it can't make target 'blank'. (And, no, I have no spaces in my path.)

I get that with both ruby-2.0.0-p247 and ruby-2.0.0-r42493, which is the latest stable snapshot. I get that on CygWin with all the build tools installed, and up-to-date. I have built many things under CygWin before, including Rubies, so I don't think I need to do more than this:

```
tar xf stable-snapshot.tar.gz
cd ruby-2.0.0-r42493/
./configure && make
```

The configure part works, and the make part fails. The spew ends near:

```
encdb.h unchanged
making enc
make[1]: Entering directory `C:/Users/Phlip/Downloads/tools/ruby/ruby-2.0.0-r42493'
make[1]: *** No rule to make target ` '.  Stop.
```

I can post the rest of the spew on request, but it's just the usual make spew.

A little help?